# How to install elasticsearch as a service using brew

Tags: elasticsearch, service, installation

I want to use brew to install elasticsearch but I don't succeed to install it as a service to be able to start it like:

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

and to be able to stop it like:

```
sudo service elasticsearch stop
```

Do you know how I can do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:** `elasticsearch` is no longer open source and so has been disabled in homebrew. Try `opensearch` instead. Thanks to the comments for pointing this out!

---

In homebrew you don't need to install sth as a service in a special way. Install it as usual and start it as a service (if the formula supports it, which elasticsearch does).

So to install:

```
brew install elasticsearch
```

and then to run as a service (with autostart on startup):

```
brew services start elasticsearch
```

Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:

```
elasticsearch
```

To stop/kill, just press `Ctrl+C` on the terminal where you executed above command

Comment: I can't stop it

Comment: I installed elasticsearch using brew and started it using the command 'brew services start elasticsearch'. However when I tried to make a get request to http://localhost:9200/ the server is not running.Any help?

Comment: I keep getting the error saying - Error: elasticsearch has been disabled because it is switching to an incompatible license. Check out `opensearch` instead! @Maccesch.

Comment: Because elasticsearch is no longer opensource. Amazon however, forked an older version from Elasticsearch and created it's own service `opensearch` which can be installed via `brew install opensearch`. Keep in mind, that it might not be able to replace elasticsearch 1:1 yet

Answer (score 2):

I was searching and found this topic.

brew install elasticsearch deprecated.

if someone find this post please use the following instead

```
brew tap elastic/tap
```

then

```
brew install elastic/tap/elasticsearch-full
```

run elastic search service

```
brew services start elastic/tap/elasticsearch-full
```

make sure elastic search is running

```
curl http://localhost:9200
```

the output should be like this:

```
"name": "Mohameds-MacBook-Pro.local",
"cluster_name": "elasticsearch_mohd",
"cluster_uuid": "KxxWtfPBS_WTJ43c8rql8Q",
"version": {
   "number": "7.17.4",
   "build_flavor": "default",
   "build_type": "tar",
   "build_hash": "79878662c54c886ae89206c685d9f1051a9d6411",
   "build_date": "2022-05-18T18:04:20.964345128Z",
   "build_snapshot": false,
   "lucene_version": "8.11.1",
   "minimum_wire_compatibility_version": "6.8.0",
   "minimum_index_compatibility_version": "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
     "tagline": "You Know, for Search"
```

referral:

https://itc-4u.com/install-elastic-search-on-macos-with-homebrew/

Answer (score 0):

to install elastic search: brew update and then brew install elasticsearch
to start the service just type in: elasticsearch
to stop the service: Ctrl + Z

more information: https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-on-mac-os-x

Comment: The original question is really: how can we have elastic search run as a service, a process that is started at system startup? With the newest brew versions it should work with `sudo brew services install elasticsearch` but that does not work for me yet.....